Error 405 while trying to send form data to a database via flask
Here's the python (flask) code where i tried sending the forms data to a mysql database via flask, but it is returning a 405 ERROR when i try to send it:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

@app.route('/process_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def process_form():
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        port='3307',
        user='root',
        password='',
        database='teste'
    )
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    insert = f'INSERT INTO info (nome, senha) VALUES ("{username}", "{password}")'

    cursor.execute(insert)
    resultado1 = cursor.fetchall()
    for linha in resultado1:
        print(linha)
        
    select = 'SELECT * FROM INFO'

    cursor.execute(select)
    resultado2 = cursor.fetchall()
    for linha in resultado2:
        print(linha)

    conn.commit()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


    return 'Dados do formulário processados e inseridos no banco de dados.'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


i tried especifying the method to allow GET method as well as POST, but it did not work
also tried inserting a JS script to make the "send" button functionallity, but it did not work as well

http 405 error message stands for method not allowed, meaning the http method (get, post, head, put, dele) you used in the http request is not supported. It has nothing to do with your database, unless you manually raise 405 error from your code in response to a database error.
